# Where does Rails store routes that do not respond to GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I want to programatically retrieve a list of all the routes in a rails application I can use the following snippet:

`Rails.application.routes.named_routes.each do |something|; end`

Each route that is returned has a `verb` method which always returns the following: `"(?-mix:^GET$)"`, indicating that the route responds to GET. So how do you find all the routes that respond to POST, DELETE etc?

Comment: The question this links to doesn't explicitly answer my question, however the answer is in there at this code snippet:````ROUTES = Rails.application.routes.routes.map do |route|
  # Turn route path spec into string; use "1" for all params
  path = route.path.spec.to_s.gsub(/\(\.:format\)/, "").gsub(/:[a-zA-Z_]+/, "1")
  verb = %W{ GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE }.grep(route.verb).first.downcase.to_sym
  { path: path, verb: verb }
end````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.select{ | r | r.verb.match 'POST' }
```

Comment: That's what I would have thought too, but in my console it produces no matching routes.

Comment: What is the output of `Rails.application.routes.routes.map &:verb`?

Comment: A list of verbs, e.g. `[/^GET$/, /^POST$/, /^DELETE$/]`

Comment: Ah! I note I made an error in my original response - I added ;0 to the end for some reason and so there was no output - have a point by way of apology!